# why i dont log out from IE when i logout from chrom in identityserver?

Tags: single-sign-on, duende-identity-server, identityserver6

I've made a Sso by Identity Server 6  and Net Core recently. when the user logs out from Chrome they remain logged into Internet Explore. I want when a user log out from one browser they log out of all browser. I use of JWT token for authentication and hold an identity token in Cookie

Comment: _"he stays logged in to Internet Explorer"_ - uhhhh, what's the story here?

Comment: _"I want when a user log out from one browser they log out of all browser."_ - This can be done, but we need **far more detail** about your current set-up - are you using front-channel or back-channel for RP+IdP comms? Are you using reference-tokens or JWT tokens? Have you configured IS's built-in session revocation functionality? (How have you set-up your persisted grant store?) etc etc

Comment: hi .. i edited my question's grammar....I use of JWT token   for authentication  and  hold 
 identity token in Cookie.

Comment: ...that's just one small detail - but we need _paragraphs of detail_ before anyone can really help you.